# If I receive a LN payment from an anon sender... is there a way to send back to this individual?

Tags: lightning-network

I see the preimage, hash, and payment request but all of those are transaction specific and unrepeatable. Any idea how it would be possible to send back the other way without knowing the individual?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no definitive way to detect the source of a payment on the Lightning Network.

However, there exists techniques (either active or passive, such as probing or some heuristics) which may be used to try to deanonymize parties involved in a payment.

So, while you can't reliably identify a party, you cannot assume it's totally anonymous either.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. I ask because i'm in the late stages of building this www.satoshie.com ... and I cannot figure out a frictionless way to do payouts ... am I down the creek w/o a paddle?

Comment: Looks like we are starting a back-and-forth conversation, you may want to join #lightning-dev on Freenode :-) To answer with another question: why do you need refund informations to be based on the Lightning Network ? EDIT: if you come at freenode feel free to ping me, same pseudo there

Comment: thanks, will join there. The site is based on micropayments (being able to place a bet of say 1 cents, on chain that would not be possible). Do you have an alternate in mind?

Comment: (Not a web dev, it might be a bad idea). Can't you just use session ids / cookies stuff to identify who's owned a refund ? And have a page asking them for an invoice in order to get refunded ? As you go, might be worth adding a basic accounting system too.